# How to use detailed brushes in sculpt mode without having to use multiresolution on the entire object?

Tags: sculpting, multiresolution, brushes

In the sculpt -> retopology workflow, it is very convenient to use textures with height information to add details "creatively", meaning you can drag them around and place them where it looks best:

[image]

The issue is, that you have to apply a multiresolution modifier to the **entire** mesh, that you'd like to use this method on. This is not feasible in many cases, for example I'd like to use this method on a sculpt of a figure I already sculpted:

[image]

If I'd apply a multiresolution modifier, I'd quickly need more ram than Google has in their servers.

If I were to just use the brush on the existing mesh, the resolution would be too low and it would get really laggy:

[image]

**Is there a way to use this creative, responsive method, with the visual feedback on a high-poly mesh?** In an ideal world, only the extra geometry needed for the brush to look good would be added, which is neglible. I know an alternative is the boolean modifier, however you can't really use it with alphas, you have to go out of sculpt mode and it is equally slow.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to isolate the torso portion of the mesh and use the brush as required.

Then you can rejoin the torso to the entire mesh. I assume you are going to retopo it.

This combined with the mirror modifier can reduce the amount of vertices for your RAM to handle.